# upgrade chefdk ruby version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chefdk

I am on windows7 and using chefdk.

Chefdk comes with ruby --version 2.1.8

but my requirement is to use ruby version 2.2.3 or later.

But I am not able to find out, how to upgrade ruby which comes with chefdk.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Giriraj

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest version of ChefDK. Version 2.3.1 should have Ruby version 2.4.2. See https://docs.chef.io/release_notes_chefdk.html